# Remove extra bracket from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In Python, I have this list:

```
results =  [[['New','York','intrepid', 'bumbling']], [['duo', 'deliver', 'good', 'one']]]
```

How do I make it the following?

```
results =  [['New', 'York', 'intrepid', 'bumbling'],['duo', 'deliver', 'good', 'one']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
new_list = [x[0] for x in results]
print (new_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

So what you got here is a list of lists which contains a single list.

My approach would be a list comprehension as follows:

```
results =  [[['New', 'York','intrepid', 'bumbling']],[['duo', 'deliver', 'good', 'one']]]
results_mod = [list(*x) for x in results]
```

This iterates over all lists of one list and unpacks it. Since it only contains one list, the `list()` call does not change anything and the result will be:

```
results_mod = [['New', 'York', 'intrepid', 'bumbling'], ['duo', 'deliver', 'good', 'one']
```